# Faucet drip after water shut off

Tags: leak, faucet, shutoff

We had a plumber out to replace our outside hose bibs.  After turning the water back on, one of our faucets in the house now has a drip.  Its nowhere close to the area that the plumber worked on.  Any reason why it would now drip?  Could it be from the initial pressure of turning the water back on?

Comment: Why worry about *why* it's leaking and just get it fixed?

Comment: When asking "why", I meant in the context of what might be the problem, to point me to a solution. And @Ecnerwal provided that solution.  And trying that before running off and replacing things saved me time and money.  That's "why".

Comment: You should put things like this in your questions to help avoid confusion. Good reasoning and sound judgement on your part. +1 for the added effort.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (and the +1).  Guess when I first saw the issue, I was thinking why did this start now, and posted as such, when in reality, what I wanted to get to was, how do I fix it?  Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning the water off and on and getting the air bubbles back out of the pipes often loosens up "crud" in the pipes. Some of that crud may be stuck in the sealing part of the valve.

Try opening it all the way and running for a while, perhaps removing the aerator first. You might get lucky and have it work free of the valve mechanism.

In many cases the "crud" is somewhat rusty. It's generally harmless but unappealing - however, if a chunk large enough lodges in the wrong place, it can cause problems.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  Thanks for the info and suggestion.

Comment: Opened both hot and cold and let it run full open, and shut off.  Seems to have solved the issue.  Thx!